# PyTorch - Using {N,H,W,C} format in customized operation

Tags: c++, pytorch

I'm thinking about upgrading some of my customized PyTorch operations to support {N,H,W,C} format. However, I'm still confused about using channel-last-format tensors in PyTorch.

First, what does `.contiguous(memory_format=torch.channels_last)` do?

```py
a=torch.randn((1, 3, 128, 128)).contiguous(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
b=torch.randn((1, 128, 128, 3))
c=torch.randn((1, 128, 128, 3)).contiguous(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
d=torch.randn((1, 128, 128, 3)).permute([0,3,1,2]).contiguous(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
```

Which tensor is truly stored with {N,H,W,C} (e.g., {1, 128, 128, 3}) in memory? a, b, or c? Btw when I inputed them to convolution layers, both b and c raised errors.

Which tensor is truly stored with {N,H,W,C} (e.g., {1, 128, 128, 3}) in memory? a, b, c, or d? Btw when I inputed them to convolution layers, both b and c raised errors.

Second, how to tell which memory format a tensor is using in CPP? In the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#writing-a-mixed-c-cuda-extension), the sample codes of creating customized operations with CPP are:

```cpp
#define CHECK_CUDA(x) TORCH_CHECK(x.device().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
#define CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x) TORCH_CHECK(x.is_contiguous(), #x " must be contiguous")
#define CHECK_INPUT_TENSOR(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)

std::vector<torch::Tensor> lltm_forward(
    torch::Tensor input,
    torch::Tensor weights,
    torch::Tensor bias,
    torch::Tensor old_h,
    torch::Tensor old_cell) {
  CHECK_INPUT(input);
  CHECK_INPUT(weights);
  CHECK_INPUT(bias);
  CHECK_INPUT(old_h);
  CHECK_INPUT(old_cell);
  return lltm_cuda_forward(input, weights, bias, old_h, old_cell);
}
```

I supposed the `x.is_contiguous()` called by `CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)` confirms `x` is {N,C,H,W} but how do I know if it is {N,H,W,C}? If `x.is_contiguous()` returns `false`, is the tensor definitely {N,H,W,C}?

```cpp
torch::Tensor my_op(const torch::Tensor &input,
                    const string &data_format) {
    if (data_format == "NCHW") {
        CHECK_INPUT_TENSOR(input)
    }
    else if (data_format == "NHWC") {
        // How do I make sure that the tensor is NHWC?
    }
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Input data_format should be \"NCHW\" or \"NHWC\".");

    torch::Tensor output = torch::zeros_like(input);          
    if (data_format == "NCHW") {
        // call cuda function for NCHW input
    }
    else if (data_format == "NHWC") {
        // call cuda function for NHWC input
    }
    return output;
```